# React router and this.props.children - how to pass state to this.props.children

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React-router for the first time and I don't know how to think in it yet. Here's how i'm loading my components in nested routes.

**entry point .js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory} >
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="models" component={Content}>
        </Route>
    </Router>, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**App.js**

```
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

So the child of my App is the Content component I sent in. I'm using Flux and my App.js has the state and listens for changes, but I don't know how to pass that state down to this.props.children. Before using react-router my App.js defines all children explicitly, so passing state was natural but I don't see how to do it now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass props to {this.props.children}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370994/how-to-pass-props-to-this-props-children)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This question boils down to, ***how do you pass props to children?***

#### June 2018 answer

**Today's tech:**

- React 16+
- [React Router 4](https://react-router.now.sh/): `react-router-dom`
- [Render Props from official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

---

Assuming some stateful component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

// some component you made
import Title from './Title'

class App extends React.Component {
  // this.state
  state = { title: 'foo' }

  // this.render
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>

        // when the url is `/test` run this Route's render function:
        <Route path="/:foobar" render={

          // argument is props passed from `<Route /`>
          routeProps => 

            // render Title component
            <Title 
              // pass this.state values
              title={this.state.title}

              // pass routeProps values (url stuff)
              page={routeProps.match.params.foobar} // "test"
            />

        } />

      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

This works because **this.props.children** is a function:

```
// "smart" component aka "container"
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { foo: 'bar' }
  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.state.foo)
  }
}

// "dumb" component aka "presentational"
const Title = () => (
  <App>
    {title => <h1>{title}</h1>}
  </App>
)
```

**[Example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ymy851xq99)**

#### My previous oldschool answer that I wouldn't recommend anymore:

Using a couple of React helper methods you can add state, props and whatever else to `this.props.children`

```
render: function() {
  var children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (child) {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      foo: this.state.foo
    })
  })

  return <div>{children}</div>
}
```

Then your child component can access this via props, `this.props.foo`.

Comment: Yea, I was reading about the children helper and saw this. Why use the Map rather than the ForEach though?

Comment: It's generally advised not to mutate data if you can help it. This is good practice in programming generally, not just for React. Only make mutations if there is no other possible solution---this is a rare case.

Comment: I agree about mutations but I guess I don't see the connection - does ForEach necessarily mutate state?

Comment: Well `cloneElement` returns a new child object so you need to return a new `children` array/object. `Children.forEach` doesn't return anything, neither does `Array.prototype.forEach`. If you don't return anything, you affect no change unless you mutate something or cause a side effect (save to database / make ajax call etc)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, works like a charm. However, I'm getting a propType validation warning from the child component, saying the props are undefined. I can use them without problems, but I don't know why these warnings are thrown? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @OleBläsing I would make another SO question and link it here if you want.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [React method "cloneElement"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement) to accomplish this. When you clone the element, you can pass in props at that time. Use the clone instead of the original in your render fn. eg:

```
    render: function() {
    var childrenWithProps = React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {someProp: this.state.someProp});
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        {childrenWithProps}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Missing curly braces around `childrenWithProps`

Comment: Would your example clone all children or just one in the case when this.props.children only has one element? I saw the other example on stackoverflow but it seemed wrong that I would need to manually iterate through them just to do basic props passing.

Comment: @Patrick If you look at my answer you'll notice `Children.map` first. This is needed, typically because `children` can be an object or an array, and in the latter case, you clone each element.

Comment: @Patrick as @azium said, my example will only work if `this.props.children` is a single object, not an array. And, `Children.map` will work, even if `this.props.children` is a single object. So their suggestion is a better option than mine.

Comment: Thanks regardless! I'm glad to have help

Answer (score 2):

There's also the option of using [Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). React-Router relies on it to give access to the Router object in the route components.

From another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35820245/1904089) I gave on a similar question:

I quickly put together an example using contexts on [codepen](http://codepen.io/alexchiri/pen/WwQVRG). `MainLayout` defines some properties that could be used by the children using the context: `users` and `widgets`. These properties are used by the `UserList` and `WidgetList` components. Notice they need to define what they need to access from the context in the `contextTypes` object.

```
var { Router, Route, IndexRoute, Link } = ReactRouter

var MainLayout = React.createClass({
  childContextTypes: {
    users: React.PropTypes.array,
    widgets: React.PropTypes.array,
  },
  getChildContext: function() {
    return {
      users: ["Dan", "Ryan", "Michael"], 
      widgets: ["Widget 1", "Widget 2", "Widget 3"]
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <header className="primary-header"></header>
        <aside className="primary-aside">
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/users">Users</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/widgets">Widgets</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </aside>
        <main>
          {this.props.children}
        </main>
      </div>
      )
  }
})

var Home = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<h1>Home Page</h1>)
  }
})

var SearchLayout = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="search">
        <header className="search-header"></header>
        <div className="results">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
        <div className="search-footer pagination"></div>
      </div>
      )
  }
})

var UserList = React.createClass({
  contextTypes: {
    users: React.PropTypes.array
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ul className="user-list">
        {this.context.users.map(function(user, index) {
          return <li key={index}>{user}</li>;  
        })}
      </ul>
      )
  }
})

var WidgetList = React.createClass({
  contextTypes: {
    widgets: React.PropTypes.array
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ul className="widget-list">
        {this.context.widgets.map(function(widget, index) {
          return <li key={index}>{widget}</li>;  
        })}
      </ul>
      )
  }
})

var Routes = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home} />
          <Route component={SearchLayout}>
            <Route path="users" component={UserList} />
            <Route path="widgets" component={WidgetList} />
          </Route> 
        </Route>
      </Router>;
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<Routes/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```