# pass {...this.state} with {this.props.children}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hi all and thanks for your time.

I see a tutorial with lynda.com for React.js.
But, it used a old version of React.
His code:

```
render: function(){
    return (
    <div>
        <Header title={this.state.title} status={this.state.status}/>
        <RouteHandler {...this.state} />
    </div>
    )
}
```

---

But i use a new version of React 15.2.1 and React-router 2.5.2.
And i don't know how pass {...this.state} with {this.props.children}

```
render: function(){ 
    return (
    <div>
        <Header title={this.state.title} status={this.state.status}/>
        {this.props.children} 
    </div>
    )
}
```

Thank you, everyone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React router and this.props.children - how to pass state to this.props.children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835670/react-router-and-this-props-children-how-to-pass-state-to-this-props-children)

Comment: Can u post a link containing your code in JSFddle or codepen. Its hard to understand from above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to pass some props to `{this.props.children}`, you can use [React.cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement).The resulting element will have the original element's props with the new props merged in shallowly.

```
render: function(){ 
    return (
    <div>
        <Header title={this.state.title} status={this.state.status}/>
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.children,this.state)} 
    </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's me again, i have to add an emit
In tutorial, with old version of React.

```
<RouteHandler **emit={this.emit}** {...this.state}/>
```

Now, how to add emit ?

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.state)} //where add emit ?
```

Thanks,

Comment: edit your original question, don't post an edit as an answer, you provided an answer here (and its not)