# pass user prop to all children react router

Tags: authentication, reactjs, react-router

I want to write a wrapper component that passes any children props. For example in a pure react auth system.

```
<Router history={ hashHistory } >
<Route path="/" component={Base}>
<Route component={Auth}>
    <Route path="/who" component={Who} />
    <Route path="/features" component={Features} />
    <Route path="/try" component={Try} />
</Route>
</Route>
</Router>
```

I want to pass a user by props to either the Who, Features or Try components from Auth, which will pull from local storage.

The silly thing I have tried to do is to manipulate this.props or this.props.children but this is not ok, what is the recommended solution?

```
class Auth extends Component {
  render() {
    //find user or null
    var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) || [];
    //this.props.user = user;
    console.log('top level router props.user', this.props.user);
    return (
    <div>
    {this.props.children}
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use `onEnter` Example of a child route will be like this `<Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />`

Comment: @KeshanNageswaran thanks for the reply, my app is a bit more particular about roles and I want to be able to evaluate a string. I wrote a small wrapper API around the base react component class I can evaluate against I'm just not sure how to pass from the top level.

I think I may need to use cloneElement

Comment: hope that [react-router-role-authentication] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-role-authorization) will cater your need i found this [blog post] (http://frontendinsights.com/role-based-authorization-using-react-router/) as well

Answer (score 0):

see this answer by Jess. React clone element is what you want.

[React router and this.props.children - how to pass state to this.props.children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835670/react-router-and-this-props-children-how-to-pass-state-to-this-props-children)

```
render() {
    var childrenWithProps = React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {someProp: this.state.someProp});
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        {childrenWithProps}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to version 4 you can use Match with your own HOC for auth.

https://react-router.now.sh/auth-workflow