# React: how to notify parent for changes

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to wrap bootstrap into components with integrated form validation.

short:
Let's say I have

```
<Form>
  <FieldGroup>
     <Field rules={'required'}/>
  </FieldGroup>
</Form>
```

Once `Field` pases validation, how can I notify `FieldGroup` (parent node) to add a class?

I created a simplified codepen version [here](http://codepen.io/kossel/pen/eBdoXW)

I would like depending on validation status, then change the state of FieldGroup So I can properly change the class name. (add `has-warning`  `has-danger` etc) and ultimately add class to the Form component.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to pass a `callback` to the child component. I just forked your codepen and added some snippet as below.

http://codepen.io/andretw/pen/xRENee

Here is the main concept,
**Make a callback function in** ***"parent"*** **component and pass it to the** ***"child"*** **component**

i.e. The child component needs an extra prop to get the callback:

```
<Form>
  <FieldGroup>
     <Field rules={'required'} cb={yourCallbackFunc}/>
  </FieldGroup>
</Form>
```

In `<FieldGroup />` (parent):

```
class FieldGroup extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: 'blue'
    }
  }

  cb (msg) {
    console.log('doing things here', msg)
  }

  render() { 
    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
     child => React.cloneElement(child, {
       cb: this.cb
     })
    )
    return (
      <div class='fields-group'>
        <label> field </label>
        { childrenWithProps }
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

In `<Field />` (child):

```
class Field extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      empty: true
    }
    this.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
  }

  validate(e){
    let val = e.target.value;
    console.log(!val);
    this.setState({empty: !val});
    //here to notify parent to add a color style!

    // do call back here or you may no need to return.
    this.props.cb(val)

    return !val;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type='text' onBlur ={(event) => this.validate(event)}/>
        {this.state.empty && 'empty'}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

And you can do the things you want in the callback function. (You can also pass a callback from `<Form />` to the grandson and get it work, but you need to rethink the design of it is good or not.)

Comment: is it using cloneElement slows the app? now every render would have to map and merge the cb,

Comment: That part is for *adding a prop to each child in this.props.children*, you can also check the comments below [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835670/react-router-and-this-props-children-how-to-pass-state-to-this-props-children). I didn't do the benchmark for this but it should be okay if you have only a few of `this.props.children` in the component.