# Get notified when React tree is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ReactDOM.render accepts an optional callback, which is executed when component is rendered:

```
ReactDOM.render(element, container[, callback])
```

Is there a similar callback in React/ReactDOM that is executed when a component in the tree (of any depth) is updated from within, i.e. using a setState?

---

- Simply providing componentDidUpdate on the root component won't do, as the method is not triggered on children update: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-yjq0r
- It is possible to subscribe to DOM tree updates using MutationObserver, but I wonder whether React provides this functionality out of the box.

Comment: How about `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: ```setState(updater[, callback])``` setState also accept a ```callback```

Comment: Yes, componentDidUpdate/setState callback, but for the whole tree.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: how to notify parent for changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644092/react-how-to-notify-parent-for-changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [React.Profiler](https://reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html):

```
<React.Profiler id="app" onRender={callback}>
  <Root />
</React.Profiler>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-lmvzk