# React + Redux: Cannot read property 'props' of null error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I have been receiving a Cannot read property 'props' of null error in th client app that I am currently building with react and redux.
I have been trying to implement a wrapper component/container for other react components in a web app as follows.(The reason I have included the contents of 4 files is that I don't know where the error is originating from)

```
main.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import store, {history} from './App/store';

import Init from './App/Init';


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Router path="/" component={Init}>
                <IndexRoute component={Container}/>
                <Route path="/view/:ItemId" component={Single}></Route>
            </Router>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('main')
);

class Container extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>hello</div>
    );
    }
}

class Single extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>hello</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Init.js

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionCreators from './ActionCreators'
import App from './App';

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
    return{
        items: state.items,
        entities: state.entities,
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
}


const Init = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

export default Init;
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, compse, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import {syncHistoryWithStore} from 'react-router-redux';

//import the root reducer
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

//import data
import {entities} from '../../data/entities';
import {items} from '../../data/items';

//create an object for the default data
const defaultState = {
    items,
    entities,
};

const store = createStore(rootReducer, defaultState);

export const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

export default store;
```

and App.js

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="content-wrapper">
                    <div className="grid-page">
                        {React.cloneElement({...this.props}.children, {...this.props})}//The error occurs here
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and here is the console log of the error

```
ReactElement.js:271 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null
    at Object.ReactElement.cloneElement (ReactElement.js:271)
    at Object.cloneElement (ReactElementValidator.js:223)
    at App.render (App.js:15)
    at App.<anonymous> (makeAssimilatePrototype.js:15)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:796
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js:795)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:822)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:362)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:258)
```

Please excuse the lack of brevity in my question, I have not found any answers on stack overflow that address the issue I am having, but if you could shed some light on what is going wrong, that would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Frankly I'm surprised you're not getting a syntax error for that. Anyways, look here for the proper usage of `React.cloneElement` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835670/react-router-and-this-props-children-how-to-pass-state-to-this-props-children/35835834#35835834

Comment: That does not work???...the "children" object is still null?

Comment: `class` doesn't get hoisted.. try putting your definition for `Container` and `Single` above your `ReadDOM.render` call

Comment: Brilliant, it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class` definitions in the spec don't get hoisted, though Babel is compiling it down to a function expression, which will hoist the variable, which is why the code doesn't crash at runtime, but the class definitions are still `undefined`

putting your `class Container` and `class Single` above your call to `ReactDOM.render` should solve this issue.