# Split Transclusion React

Tags: react-router, reactjs

What I'm wanting to do is have children components influence children components of its parent. Tangibly: I want my content components to be able to inject components into my header and sidebar elements that are pre-defined.

Router:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={AppRoot}>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/list" component={List}/>
    <Route path="/profile/:uid" component={Profile}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

App Root:

```
class AppRoot extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      header_elements: <div>HELLO???</div>
    };
    console.log(this);
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <AppBar className="app_bar" title="Soulhart" showMenuIconButton={false}>
            <div id="nested_content">
              {this.state.header_elements}
            </div>
          </AppBar>
          <div>
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Home:

```
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<strong>Home</strong>);
  }
}
```

My navigation and header are defined inside AppRoot, but I'm not sure how to have Home set the AppRoot.header_elements value. Is there a simpler way of doing this, or is what I want impossible?

Comment: read this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835670/react-router-and-this-props-children-how-to-pass-state-to-this-props-children then define a method which sets your app state, and pass that method down to your child components

Answer (score 0):

The way you do this is to have a property of type func on your child component -

```
Home.propTypes = {
    updateRoot : React.PropTypes.func
};
```

And then call that from home. Ofcouse, you would need to wire it up in the router

```
 <Route path="home" component={() => <Home updateRoot={this.handleUpdateRoot}/>}/>
```

Comment: this results in an error where `this` is undefined.